# Ethics of scratch boards in puzzles

Tags: rules, tournament, etiquette, cheating, chess.com

Re these questions:

1. [would a board for calculating "non-blindfold" help GMs in slow games?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/43505/would-a-board-for-calculating-non-blindfold-help-gms-in-slow-games)
2. [Ethics of scratch boards in live games](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/45051/ethics-of-scratch-boards-in-live-games)

There is a built-in feature of a 'scratch board' in correspondence but not in [puzzles](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/45053/ethics-of-scratch-boards-in-puzzles) or [live games](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/45051/ethics-of-scratch-boards-in-live-games). By scratch board, I mean you have a physical board or an analysis board where you move pieces around to see things, but of course **the engine is off**.

Also, I'm thinking mainly of untimed puzzles, but I guess the answer is the same even for timed like lichess [puzzle storm](https://lichess.org/storm), lichess [puzzle racer](https://lichess.org/racer), [chesstempo](https://wp.me/p1w4Rr-3dY)'s '[blitz](https://chesstempo.com/manual/en/manual.html#blitzversusstandard)' (and maybe 'mixed' - I haven't tried) or blitztactics.com's '[rated](https://blitztactics.com/rated)'.

Here's my pitch for scratch boards (in either live games or puzzles) :

I'll begin with some [what](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7hENl2Lp_I)abou[tism](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/88625/would-it-be-have-been-unhelpful-for-hans-niemann-to-bring-up-magnus-carlsens):

1. Like I said before, I believe [time management extensions are much worse](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/45048/how-isnt-a-time-management-extension-cheating-unethical).

Scratch boards tell you **only what you think**. They just help you see more clearly. With scratch boards, everything is from **your thinking only**. You're just externalising your thinking. I don't think they're any different from [calculators in poker](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/11405/n00b-ethics-question-about-calculators-in-online-poker-or-choker) (but not [GTO solvers](https://www.pokernews.com/news/2020/10/what-is-meant-by-real-time-assistance-rta-38054.htm) - that's outright using an engine) that tell you your hand strength.

The time management extension tells you what **another player thinks** (namely a machine for evaluation bar cheating and an automated process based on real time information for the time management extensions).

Actually, here are 2 things that distinguish scratch boards, and even like [arrows](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/26821/are-banter-blitz-players-who-draw-arrows-on-the-board-during-the-game-breaking-t) if those ever get removed, from a time management extension:

2. I think statistics (evaluation, move times, etc) are completely useless to determine if someone 'cheated' by using a scratch board or arrows. But I believe you can detect time management extension cheating like how you can detect evaluation bar cheating & even the regular telling-you-moves cheating.
3. Scratch boards & arrows I believe [won't help superGMs](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/43505/would-a-board-for-calculating-non-blindfold-help-gms-in-slow-games/45052#45052). Same as poker: I don't believe [poker calculators](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/11405/n00b-ethics-question-about-calculators-in-online-poker-or-choker) (but not GTO solvers) would help poker pro's. But time management extensions would!

Now for puzzles specifically:

4. At least in untimed puzzles, I don't really see how it's different from correspondence to create a lichess study and really think about the puzzle for days. You could say it won't necessarily help you in correspondence, but I think it's the [timed puzzle rating (like on chesstempo)](https://wp.me/p1w4Rr-3dY) that actually provides a better expectation live rating. I defy anyone to provide statistics that show live rating doesn't correlate much more to timed rating than untimed rating. To make a counterstrike/valorant analogy, I view untimed puzzles like 'training' at your own pace where you're graded *in an absolute sense* and timed puzzles like 'deathmatch', where you're graded *in a relative sense* based on how well you do against other players.
5. And as for timed puzzles, I don't think this'll make a difference. People who can solve certain puzzles without a scratch board would be ahead of you.

**Question: Even granting arguendo [scratch boards are cheating/unethical in live games](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/45051/ethics-of-scratch-boards-in-live-games), how are they cheating/unethical in (rated) puzzles, in particular while time management extensions are allowed/ethical?**